# error : - The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e6sm29167643pfj.71 - gsmtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to send a keycode through email but everytime I am getting this error:- "**The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e6sm29167643pfj.71 - gsmtp.** ". I think the problem is with the SendMails() but I am not getting what is that problem.Please help me out.I am using Visual studio community 2015?

Below is the code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Web.Util;


public partial class admin_ExamSchedule : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
            int examtypeid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["examtypeid"].ToString());
            ddlExamIdNotAttempted.DataSource = objAttemptexam.getNotAttemptedExamId(examtypeid);
            ddlExamIdNotAttempted.DataValueField = "ExamId";
            ddlExamIdNotAttempted.DataTextField = "ExamName";
            ddlExamIdNotAttempted.DataBind();

            //  Response.Write("<script>alert('Must Select Any One')</script>");
            //ddlExamIdAttempted.DataSource = objAttemptexam.getAttemptedExamId();
            //ddlExamIdAttempted.DataValueField = "ExamId";
            //ddlExamIdAttempted.DataTextField = "ExamName";
            //ddlExamIdAttempted.DataBind();
    }
}
BALexam objAttemptexam = new BALexam();
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            objAttemptexam.uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"].ToString());
            objAttemptexam.ExamReqDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["preferdate"]).ToString();
            objAttemptexam.ExamAssignDate =txtAssignExamDate.Text;
            objAttemptexam.ExamId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlExamIdNotAttempted.SelectedValue);
            objAttemptexam.ExamRequestId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ExamRequestId"].ToString());
         //   objAttemptexam.UserName = Session["User"].ToString();
            objAttemptexam.KeyCode = txtKeyCode.Text;

            string strMsg;
            SendMails();
            int i = objAttemptexam.InsertScheduleExam(out strMsg);
            if (i > 1)
            {
                ClearData();
                LblMsg.Text = strMsg;
            }
            else
                LblMsg.Text = strMsg;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
}
void SendMails()
{
    MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
    objMail.From = "abc27@gmail.Com";
    objMail.To = "def4444@gmail.com";
    objMail.Subject = "OnLineExam Schedule.";
    objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
    objMail.Body = "Your Key                 : " + txtKeyCode.Text + "" + "\n" +
                   "Your ExamId              : " + Convert.ToInt32(ddlExamIdNotAttempted.SelectedValue) + "" + "\n" +
                   "Your ExamDate            : " + txtAssignExamDate.Text;

    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

    SmtpMail.Send(objMail);
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Dhanush", "<script>alert('Key Send to Student Successfully...')</script>");
}

private void ClearData()
{
    txtAssignExamDate.Text = txtKeyCode.Text = "";
}
protected void ddlExamIdAttempted_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlExamIdNotAttempted.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
}
protected void ddlExamIdNotAttempted_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,     EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("frmShowExamRequest.aspx");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your error message, it clearly states the Problem: you don't use a secure connection and Gmail does not allow to send over an insecure connection.

By the way: The SmtpMail class is deprecated and it is recommended to use System.Net.SmtpClient instead.